# MySQL Left Join - gives the same result multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to coding, and I have run into a SQL problem that I hope you can help.
I'm using PHP and MySQL.

The problem is that I'm joining to tables together, but I get the same result more than ones. I only need the ad's ones with the latest created date from payments.

I want to show some ads from one table and join with another table where it's defined when it was last paid for.

```
Ad's table:
Id | Title

Payment table:
Id | ad_id | amount | created
```

I can have multiple records in Payment table for each ad and when I Left join I get each ad the same amount of time as I have records for it in Payments.

I have tried this:
1.

```
SELECT ads.title, payments.created 
FROM ads 
LEFT JOIN ( Select ads_id, created from payments ORDER BY id asc limit 1) as payments on payments.ads_id = ads.id
```

-- Gives me the correct number of ads, but only created for the first one

```
SELECT ads.*, payments.created
FROM ads
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.ads_id=ads.id
```

-- Gives me an ad for each record in payments

Comment: To expand on what catcon said in his answer below, when using aggregate functions (such as `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, `MAX()`...) you need to group the results using  `GROUP BY`. Other database engines such as SQL Server absolutley requires this, for good reasons. MySQL is quite loose with this, but you still need to use `GROUP BY` on *at least* one column when using aggregate functions.

Comment: It gives you a record for each payment that is associated with each ad, which is what you've asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `group by` to group all the payment from an ad, and use `max()` to get the latest payment of that ad:

```
SELECT ads.*, max(payments.created)
FROM ads
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.ads_id=ads.id group by payments.ads_id
```

Comment: Yes! (High five)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. It worked like a charm :)

Comment: No worries mate :)

Comment: I sort of have a similar problem with som joins.
I have this Ad, and an ad can have multiple pictures sorted by a value (sortorder).
Now i want my ad and only one picture (filename). The picture i want has the lowest sortorder

Table are ‘ads’ and ‘ads_pictures’.

How do i do that? :)
Sorry if this question needs it’s own thread

Comment: I created a new topic instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381032/how-to-join-two-table-and-get-the-correct-records

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT AD.ID , AD.TITLE, FINAL_PAYMENT.AMOUNT, FINAL_PAYMENT,CREATED
FROM AD 
JOIN 
( SELECT AD_ID, AMOUNT , CREATED FROM PAYMENT P1
  WHERE CREATED = (SELECT MAX(CREATED) FROM PAYMENT P2 
                  WHERE P1.AD_ID = P2.AD_ID
                  GROUP BY P2.AD_ID
                  )
 ) FINAL_PAYMENT
 ON
 AD.ID = FINAL_PAYMENT.AD_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you want to show both the date and the associated amount, one, typical solution (at least, pre-MySQL 8) looks like this:

```
SELECT a.*
     , p.amount
     , p.created
  FROM ads
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM payments x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT ads_id, MAX(created) created FROM payments GROUP BY ads_id ) y
          ON y.ads_id = x.ads_id
         AND y.created = x.created
     ) p
    ON p.ads_id = a.id
```

or something like that